# echo number format round

Tags: wordpress, rounding, money-format

in word press I am trying to echo price like round last 3 digit.

Example
$price= 15.786.625;

I whant after echo price like this

price=15.786.000

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I find a way do it this.

Say

```
$price=4,316,028 
$pricecarp=round($price/1000)*1000;

<?php 
    echo number_format($pricecarp, 0, '.', ',');
?>
Result= 4,316,000
```